# Antes funcionaba, ahora da error - CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Pues es un simple cout de una variable entera. El breakpoint salta en la línea del cout.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int entero = 15;
    cout<<entero;

    return 0;
}
```

El error es:

> Program recieved signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault

Answer (score -2):

Prueba a hacerlo asi.
Usa este ejemplo para ir probando

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//El valor de la variable que mostrar en pantalla
string salida1 = "Ejemplo de salida";

//el valor que le damos a la variable
int numero = 15;

//Este valor se concatena
string salida2 = "Hola mundo.";

//se concatenan y muestran valores en la pantalla con el cout
cout << salida1 << " " << numero << ". " << salida2 << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Con este código me salta el siguiente error, tanto en el modo build and run como en debugger:
"No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ en la biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos"

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Cómo debería _ir probando_? Trata de explicar brevemente tus respuestas para que cualquiera que las use, sepa qué está pasando

Comment: @sytlink cualquier intento adicional o info adicional que quieras aclarar, ponla en tu pregunta, editándola y **añadiendo** lo que necesites, debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: Puse comentarios en su dia me ayudo a ir entendiendo como va

Comment: Este codigo funciona correctamente pero me poneis -2? si esto no funciona es que tendra un problema en mas parte del codigo que no se ha  mostrado. @sytlink no puedes coger copiar y pegar y que funcione x arte de magia no te he dado toda la pagina entera te dado el cacho adaptalo